# Can the hulk die?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

If you have seen 'avengers:age of ultron' there is a scene where scarlette witch shows stark what will happen in the future if he takes the scepter but at the top of the steps where all the avengers lay dead is the hulk but my intensions were that the hulk couldnt die as in the first avengers fury tells agent romanoff to escort dr banner to his room and then he says something about the cell was there just incase and then banner turns and says 'what incase you needed to kill me? Well you cant, i know because i've tried' anyone have any suggestions on this??

Comment: This is a question purely about the MCU, so it cannot be a duplicate of a question purely about the comics. Related? Yes. Duplicate? No way.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with this question:

1. Scarlet Witch can't predict the future.  She can mess with people's heads, and in this case, she was showing Tony his greatest fear.
2. The Hulk isn't dead in the vision.  We see him twitching, and lying there in pain.  He's clearly severely injured, but he's not dead.

So this vision is not really a good example of the Hulk dying.

Banner's suicide attempt indicates that the Hulk can come out as a self-defense mechanism, which is handy.  But we already knew the Hulk was bulletproof, since bullets are one of the first things his enemies try to use on him.

We don't have enough information in the MCU on whether that Hulk can be killed.  At the very least he seems to be one of the most resilient Avengers.

Comment: 3. No punctuation